# What is range from -128 to 127 in character data type?

Tags: c++

I was just reviewing data types on codecademy and saw the description about char data type. It says:

> Characters typically require 1 byte of memory space and range from -128 to 127.

What is "range from -128 to 127"? For more clarification here's a screenshot:

[image]]

Comment: That's the range of values that a  signed `char` can hold...

Comment: Characters are represented within a program by their numerical values (e.g. `a` is 97 if using ASCII) and so `char` is really an integer type.  However that claim is not universally true; on many platforms `char` is unsigned and ranges from 0 to 255.  More exotic ranges are also possible.

Answer (score 0):

A signed 8-bit integer can represent the numbers from -128 to 127. The ASCII encoding associates those numbers with characters.

Answer (score -1):

That means that type `char` can store a value from -128 to 127. And the system will change that number into a character using ACSII. If you assign it to a value bigger than 127 or lower than -128, it will result in an overflow. which result to undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that overflow of a signed integer type is *undefined behavior*, which means that you cannot demonstrate it with a code snippet.

Comment: The system's display will treat `char` values as characters according to the character encoding that the system uses. That is often ASCII (almost always, these days), but there are other character encodings.